# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing._private

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to run tensorflow:

[image]

it turned out

```
from numpy.testing._private.pytesttester import PytestTester
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing._private'

[image]

numpy/**init**.py look like this:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, your question should be self-contained.

Comment: Have you installed numpy?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I installed tensorflow. Solved the issue by upgrading pip :

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

and installing numpy again :

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
```